# How do I set combobox read-only or user cannot write in a combo box only can select the given items?

Tags: c#, combobox

I am facing a problem in setting the combo property such that only user can select the values form given items, but I cannot write in the combo box.

How can I do so in C#?

Comment: This question has been asked before. Please see here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85702/how-can-i-make-a-combobox-non-editable-in-net

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Just change the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`. Or if you want it completely read only you can set `Enabled = false`, or if you don't like the look of that I sometimes have two controls, one readonly textbox and one combobox and then hide the combo and show the textbox if it should be completely readonly and vice versa.

Comment: But please note: readonly != disabled.

Comment: @Henk: Yep, that's why I said "if you don't like the look of that..." since that's usually the main issue people find with disabling a control rather than setting it as readonly.

Comment: thanx buddy it was simple but if you don't know about this it is a mystery for you, thanx it works

Comment: too bad the combobox cannot show default text and have a dropdownlist style at the same time.

Answer (score 21):

I think you want to change the setting called "DropDownStyle" to be "DropDownList".

Answer (score 15):

In the keypress event handler:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: Best solution! Thanks

Comment: That does not prevent deleting a selected text in the combo box.

Comment: Very good solution but vulnerable to the "Delete" button and right-click on combobox -> Selecting Delete option.

Answer (score 9):

Make the DropDownStyle to DropDownList

```
stateComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
    private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // comboBox1 is readonly
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
```

Comment: The only solution that allows for an initial text but still does not allow the user to change the text in the `ComboBox`. Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to change the DropDownStyle property to DropDownList. It will help.