# Leaving the dropdown enabled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I want to disable a `combobox`, but at the same time I want to let the users see the other options available (that is, I want to enable the `dropdown`).

By default, when `ComboBox.Enabled = false`, the `dropdown` is also disabled (nothing happens when we click on the `combobox`).

My first thought is to leave it enabled and handle the `ComboBox.SelectedIndex event` to set it back to the default value (I will just need to gray it out in some way.)

I am wondering if there is any native functionality like this that I am missing, or if there would be other way of doing it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392098/how-to-make-combobox-in-winforms-readonly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a *hacky* workaround, but it should accomplish something similar to your request:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ComboBox _dummy;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // set the style
        comboBox1.DropDownStyle = 
            System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        // disable the combobox
        comboBox1.Enabled = false;

        // add the dummy combobox
        _dummy = new ComboBox();
        _dummy.Visible = false;
        _dummy.Enabled = true;
        _dummy.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.Controls.Add(_dummy);

        // add the event handler
        MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
    }

    void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var child = this.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location);
        if (child == comboBox1)
        {
            if (!comboBox1.Enabled)
            {
                // copy the items
                _dummy.Items.Clear();
                object[] items = new object[comboBox1.Items.Count];
                comboBox1.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);
                _dummy.Items.AddRange(items);

                // set the size and position
                _dummy.Left = comboBox1.Left;
                _dummy.Top = comboBox1.Top;
                _dummy.Height = comboBox1.Height;
                _dummy.Width = comboBox1.Width;

                // switch visibility
                comboBox1.Visible = !(_dummy.Visible = true);
            }
        }
        else if (child != _dummy)
        {
            // switch visibility
            comboBox1.Visible = !(_dummy.Visible = false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a Combobox if you don't want the Combobox functionality. Use a ListView instead.

Answer (score 1):

A "What You See Is What You Can't Get" Combobox seems a bad idea.
I suggest using ListBox instead.

Answer (score 0):

If using a `ListBox` as other answers suggested is not convenient. There is a way by creating a custom combobox and adding a `ReadOnly` property. Try this code :

```
class MyCombo : System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
{
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
    public int currentIndex;

    public MyCombo()
    {
        currentIndex = SelectedIndex ;
    }

    protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ReadOnly && Focused)
            SelectedIndex = currentIndex;

        currentIndex = SelectedIndex;

        base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
    }

}
```

Usually the background color of read-only controls should not change, so I haven't done that part.